# Next.Js 13: Redux Provider is showing something other than the store

Tags: redux, next.js, react-redux

So I'm trying out Next.Js 13 and I'm getting some strange behavior with the redux provider. Instead of seeing my slices of state, I'm seeing some objects called tree,cache,prefetchCache, pushRef, focusAndScrollRef, and canonicalUrl. I'm also fairly new to Next.JS regardless. Here's my setup:

```
// client/app/layout.tsx

import React from "react";
import Providers from "./providers";

'use client' // <-- tried with both use client and without

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
    return (
      <html lang="en">
        <head />
            <body>
        <Providers>
                {children}
        </Providers>
            </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
```

```
// client/app/providers.tsx

'use client'

import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import {store} from '../src/redux/store'

const Providers = ({children}:React.PropsWithChildren) => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            {children}
        </Provider>
    )
}

export default Providers
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, it's a nextJs bug. You can find more information here : https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/3154

In the tabs in your redux tool you will have the "next/router" where you will find all the object like tree, cache.. and if ou select the next tab you will find current nextjs store.

Make sur to create the store like this :

```
export function makeStore() {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: combineReducers({
      search: searchReducer,
      language: languageReducer
    }),
    devTools: true
  });
}

export const store = makeStore();
```